# Unexpected response from import service: Invalid Authentication

Tags: jss

I'm trying to perform the command to deploy my application to a remote CM server

`jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary`

but I receive the following error

Sending package sitecore\package\internal-portal.1598564849342.manifest.zip to http://internal.local:44001/sitecore/api/jss/import...
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Forbidden
Body: **Invalid authentication**.

Has anyone ran into this problem before?  Other posts talking about "Forbidden" statuses had different body messages.

Here's some other details

- My CM server is running from a Docker container on my laptop with port 80 mapped to 44001.
- I've executed a `jss deploy config` and manually copied the 2 config files from my local `App_Config/Include/zzz` to the server's `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Config\Include\zzz`
- Given the `sitecore\JSS Import Service Users` full permissions to the `/sitecore` item and all it's descendants.
  [image]
- Here's my scjssconfig.json
  [image]
- In my hosts file, I have `internal.local` mapped to 127.0.0.1

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: As you are using docker containers, this is what you need to do. https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/369

Comment: Thanks Vincent.  I'll have to give that a try.  Hopefully Sitecore will release a fix soon though since that's quite a hacky workaround.  The thread says they were aiming for JSS 14, but I the issue is still open and I don't see anything mentioned in the release notes about fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate test

Once you run above, you will get error message saying expected certificate (something like F3:AC:61:. ... . . . . ) but recieved test

Now again run jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate F3:AC:61:. ... . . . .

Comment: The endpoints from the OP are not HTTPS. This is a specific issue with docker as it does not take into consideration of the port number.